# Global variable in python flask claims it is being referenced before usage in 1 of 5 functions using it

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2, flash-message

I get the following error when viewing my page on the browser.

```
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 228, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/jMessage/app/views.py", line 66, in admin_edit_groups
    if not g.user.admin:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'g' referenced before assignment
```

Here is my python code using Flask for routing. The first function is the code I used in every single admin route that works perfectly, but for some reason the admin_edit_groups route throws this error.What am I missing?

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, request, \
    g, jsonify, send_from_directory

@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def admin():
    if not g.user.admin:
        flash('Page unacessible.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('admin.html',title='Admin') 

@app.route('/admin_edit_groups', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def admin_edit_groups():
    if not g.user.admin:
        flash('Page unacessible.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = AddGroupForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        if not Group.query.filter_by(name=form.groupname.data).count()>0:
            g=Group(name=form.groupname.data)
            db.session.add(g)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Added Group name ' + form.groupname.data)
        else:
            flash('Group: ' + form.groupname.data + ' already exists.')
    groups=Group.query.all()
    return render_template('admin_edit_groups.html',title='Admin', form=form, groups=groups)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using another `g` inside your function, this will overwrite global `g`.

```
if not Group.query.filter_by(name=form.groupname.data).count()>0:
    g=Group(name=form.groupname.data)  # Here it is, rename it.
    db.session.add(g)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: why is it not using the global variable if it appears above in the code, doesn't the above code run and then the variable is reassigned?

Comment: @0TTT0 If it works as you said, it will be much more ambiguous. You need to carefully review your code in order to find whether it is a global one or a local one. This will be a disaster if you have a big function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for seeing that. I did not noticed I was using g inside the function as well. I also don't understand why that would throw an error even though I am happy it did, that would of really broken my global g.